# Cannot find Accesskey Secret Alibaba Cloud

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I want to install maxcompute command line tool ot odps command line tool, but cannot get Accesskey Secret for the account.

I am following this tutorial: https://www.alibabacloud.com/getting-started/projects/getting-started-with-alibaba-cloud-maxcompute?spm=a3c0i.8276372.1196449.211.5cbc6ed63Re8ew

Answer (score 1):

For an alibaba cloud root account access key, you can create one in the console, Goto the top right corner and select security console, here you either copy an existing key and secret pair or create a new one, refer to the following documentation link:

Create an AccessKey - General Reference| Alibaba Cloud 
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/53045.htm

Answer (score 0):

I wish you to know two things.

1. Accesskey Secret only could download once, you could create in the security console.
2. if you lost the excel or the code, you need recreate a new one.
3. I do not recommend you to use root accesskey ,it is not safety. please create one IAM role give limited access.